# Работа с множеством свойств у объекта (php)

Tags: php, ооп

В общем, такой вопрос. Допустим есть абстрактный объект продукт, с множеством полей (цена, название и т.д.) и полей этих допустим до двух десятков. Как правильно с ними работать и организовать доступ к ним? Создавать огромное кол-во сеттеров-геттеров? И допустим, при обновлении состояния объекта в бд, нужно взять все свойства и в едином запросе сделать update? С orm я не особо знаком да и задача в общем-то не подразумевает его использования, но такого рода я заданиями не занимался, отсюда и вопрос про организацию - как правильно оформить такой объект чтобы было удобно обращаться к его свойствам и изменять его отображение, допустим, в бд. Спасибо!

Comment: А использовать какой-нибудь ActiveQuery не пробовали?

Comment: @ilyaplot, нет не пробовал. Да и вопрос, наверное, больше по проектированию объекта. Как, допустим, поступать, если свойств у него много? Для каждого писать сеттер-геттер? Может какой-то другой подход есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> С orm я не особо знаком да и задача в общем-то не подразумевает его
>   использования

И

> как правильно оформить такой объект чтобы было удобно обращаться к его
>   свойствам и изменять его отображение, допустим, в бд.

Противоречат друг другу в слове БД :)

Хотите писать объект в БД - используйте ORM (прикрутите чужую, например ту же Doctrine, или свою). Там уже есть некие правила по работе со свойствами.

Если просто объект в рантайме - смотрите по тому, как вы с ним планируете работать.

В любом случае, хотите валидировать входящие аргументы или организовать взаимодействие между свойствами (одно зависит от другого) - организуйте доступ к свойствам через методы. Если объект просто некое состояние без логики - удобнее делать просто публичные свойства.

Какими методами делать (getters, setters, магические `__get`, `__set` или `ArrayAccess`) - сугубо дело вкуса. При желании можно даже извратиться и например на  `__call($name)` повесить разбор метода `(get|set)SomeProperty` и выполнять операцию над этим свойством, но при этом потеряете на анализаторе кода (PhpStorm).

P.S. Если объект содержит слишком много свойств это повод задуматься о том, всё ли с ним в порядке и нет ли смысла сделать декомпозицию.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать общий геттер и сеттер и атрибуты объекта хранить в массие, скажем, в protected $_attributes; Создайте объект с __get и __set. Для удобства можно использовать системный интерфейс ArrayAccess. Обновлять при сохранении можно все записи или хранить копию $this->_attributes и строить запрос на update только в том случае, если элемент массива был изменен, но не вижу ничего плохого в обновлении всех полей сразу.

Реализуйте методы update, select, insert и заполняйте аттрибуты значениями из бд. На каждую строку можно создавать свой экземпляр модели. Советую почитать http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: Спасибо, в общем-то эти два ответа все разъяснили.